# Starting problems connecting NodeJS and R using r-script

Tags: javascript, r, node.js

I am trying to call a R-script from a js-file but I always get `null` as a return value

My folder-structure is as following

-R_test
--example.js
--helloWorld.R

example.js looks as follows:

```js
var R = require("r-script");

var out = R('helloWorld.R')
    .callSync();

console.log(out);
```

and helloWorld.R looks as like this:

```
print("Hello World")
```

Looking at the only other question I could find similar to mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42564830/r-integration-with-node-js) my syntax is correct. Changing the js-file to

```js
var R = require("r-script");

var out = R('helloWorld.R')
    .data("Hello World)
    .callSync();

console.log(out);
```

and helloWorld.R to

```
print(input)
```

should according to the [readme of r-script](https://github.com/joshkatz/r-script#r-script) print the data `Hello World` but it also just returns `null`

If there is any better way to run a R-script from a nodeJS-file please let me know

Comment: I'm not sure that `r-script` npm package is actively maintained. I couldn't get it to work with v12+. I used [fridgerator/r-script](https://github.com/fridgerator/r-script) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [dcruvolo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5963303/dcruvolo) I got it working. Here is how the js-file needs to look:

```
const { R } = require('@fridgerator/r-script')

let r = new R('./members.R')

r.call()
  .then(response => console.log(response))
  .catch(e => console.log('error : ', e))
```

And here is the .R-file:

```
members <- c(129, 1, 5,  3,  2,  1,  21,  1,  8,  7,  0,  1,  1,  1,  110,  0,  0,  5,  1,  0,  0,  0)

membersSorted <- sort(members, decreasing = TRUE)

# Graph cars using blue points overlayed by a line 
plot(membersSorted, type="o", col="blue")

# Create a title with a red, bold/italic font
title(main="Members", col.main="red", font.main=4)

png(filename="members.png")
plot(membersSorted, type="o", col="blue")
dev.off()
```